# youtube regex swallows remaining text

Tags: php, regex, youtube, preg-match-all, str-replace

I'm doing `preg_match_all` and `str_replace` on a block of text to grab YouTube-urls and replace them with the correct embed code.

Let's say I have the following block of text:

```
"bla bla bla bla <-youtube-url-> last few words"
```

Everything works fine - the youtube-url is replaced with the embed code etc. However, the "**last few words**" disappears from the final output after str_replace is run. I'm suspecting that the regex is swallowing everything after the url... This is what I'm using to match and extract YouTube ID's:

```
%(?:youtube\.com/(?:[^/]+/.+/|(?:v|e(?:mbed)?)/|.*[?&]v=)|youtu\.be/)([^"&?/ ]{11})%i
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

**Update:**

I just discovered that the problem only happens if the youtube url has any trailing parameters. The following input swallows **last few words**:

```
'www.youtube.com/watch?v=XXXXXXXXX&parameter=data last few words'
```

But if the input is like this:

```
'www.youtube.com/watch?v=XXXXXXXXX last few words'
```

it works fine. Can anyone help with the needed adjustments for the regular expression?

Comment: Can you post a small snippet of HTML that contains the video link and surrounding html?

Comment: How is that relevant? The block of text to be parsed is user input from a textarea.

Comment: well it wasn't obvious that a "block of text" was a textarea or user input at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My bad. There was no problem with the regex, as I first suspected.

I was passing the user input to the PHP handler without escaping the input via [encodeURIComponent()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) first. Thus, the handler assumed `&parameter=data` was the next input parameter - resulting in a broken POST variable.

Sorry for my incompetence, and thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 1):

I usually break up complicated alternations to find out whats going on.
It appears you might have trouple with the last term `[^"&?/ ]{11}`, but not sure
what you are trying to do. (below is in Perl)

```
$samp = 'www.youtube.com/watch?v=XXXXXXXXX&parameter=data last few words';

$regex = qr%

(?:
    youtube\.com/
    (?:
        ( [^/]+/.+/ )    # 1
      | 
        (                # 2 
            v
          | e(?:mbed)?/
        )
      |
        ( .*[?&]v= )     # 3
    )
  |

    ( youtu\.be/ )     #4
)

( [^"&?/ ]{1,11} )     # 5, was {11}

(.*)$                  # 6 the remainder

%xi;


if ( $samp =~ /$regex/ )
{
  # just print what matched
    print "all: '$&' \n";
    print "1:   '$1' \n";
    print "2:   '$2' \n";
    print "3:   '$3' \n";
    print "4:   '$4' \n";
    print "5:   '$5' \n";
    print "6:   '$6' \n";
}
```

Output:

```
all: 'youtube.com/watch?v=XXXXXXXXX&parameter=data last few words'
1:   ''
2:   ''
3:   'watch?v='
4:   ''
5:   'XXXXXXXXX'
6:   '&parameter=data last few words'
```

Answer (score 1):

Change the `.+` to `\S+` so that you don't capture whitespace as part of the regex.

```
%(?:youtube\.com/(?:[^/]+/\S+/|(?:v|e(?:mbed)?)/|.*[?&]v=)|youtu\.be/)([^"&?/ ]{11})%i
```

The `.*` was capturing the entire line, and the rest of your regex wasn't doing anything.

Comment: Yes, this is what I need. However, I tried your suggestion, and same result :( Perhaps I'm messing it up elsewhere...

Answer (score 0):

I'm not clear on what exactly you are trying to do.  But I suggest that you try a regex tester tool - like [this one](http://cheeso.members.winisp.net/srcview.aspx?file=WinForms-RegexTester.zip), but there are others.  it lets you visually examine the results of regex.

[image]